# Update controls while printing using printdocument in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I am printing a panel with all its controls Inside. My problem is that I want to make a counter Inside this panel and increase its value for each pages printed. I tried incrementing the counter Inside my PrintPage event but this isn't working. Would it be possible to add multiple printpage events with increased counter for every page ? Here's my not working code. Thanks for giving me advices about how I could do this printing...

```
 private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(toPrint) && nbrPrint < nbrPages)
            {


                Rectangle m = panel1.ClientRectangle;


                Bitmap imaag = new Bitmap(m.Width, m.Height);
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(imaag, m);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(imaag, e.MarginBounds);
                nbrPrint++;
                compteurPrint++;
                cpt.Text = compteurPrint.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
```

nbrPrint is the pages printed, nbrPages the number of pages asked to print, compteurPrint the value I need to print in the page (which needs to be incremented), cpt is the label (Inside panel1) in which I show compteurPrint.

Since I do this:

```
 pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
 pd.Print();
```

Can I do:

```
while (nbrPrint < nbrPages)
{
     pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
     compteurPrint++;
}
pd.Print();
```

I think it would be the same result as what I'm currently doing…
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `HasMorePages` property on `PrintPageEventArgs` to tell it that there are more pages to print.

```
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (File.Exists(toPrint) && nbrPrint < nbrPages)
    {
      Rectangle m = panel1.ClientRectangle;


      Bitmap imaag = new Bitmap(m.Width, m.Height);
      panel1.DrawToBitmap(imaag, m);

      e.Graphics.DrawImage(imaag, e.MarginBounds);
      nbrPrint++;
      compteurPrint++;
      cpt.Text = compteurPrint.ToString();
      e.HasMorePages = true; // Set this to true as long as there are more pages to print. It defaults to false.
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {

  }
}
```

Checkout the Microsoft documentation for an example: [PrintDocument.PrintPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem setting PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.Copies to 1 and
 if (nbrPrint >= nbrPages)
                          e.HasMorePages = false;
                     else
                          e.HasMorePages = true;